# How to superscript character in node.js

Tags: node.js, superscript

does anyone know how to create a superscript character in node.js? I am trying to superscript '®':

```
let tm = '®'; 
let tm = tm.sup();
```

However, this returns `<sup>®</sup>`

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `String.prototype.sup()` is designed to use in HTML page. Also, it is deprecated and removed from the Web standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. You can display some superscript unicode characters (Ex. ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰⁺⁻), but '®'(`\u00AE`) does not have a superscript version.

Node.js does not support text styling itself. With terminal support, you can add modifiers / colors / background colors but not superscript. Please check [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) if you are interested.

Please note the `String.prototype.sup()` method is designed for HTML page, that's why it will wrap the text with `<sup>` tag. Also, it is deprecated and removed from the Web standard. It should not be used any more.